# NGINX Lua Basic HTTP Authorization/Authentication Allow Certain Number of Attempts

Tags: nginx, lua, authorization, basic-authentication

I'm trying to use a Lua script I found on this Git Repository: https://github.com/knq/nginx-crowd-lua/blob/master/crowd-auth.lua to authorize users to restricted content against an Atlassian Crowd user management system.

What happens when I use this script as is is that if a user enters in an incorrect username/password, then the browser returns a 403 Forbidden response, without allowing the user to try again unless the user closes the browser and goes back to the page.

What I'm trying to do is allow 3 attempts to log in before the 403 page is displayed.

I've tried looping this script, but either the loop doesn't work, and an incorrect user/pass goes straight to the 403 page on the first attempt, or the loop is infinite, allowing unlimited attempts.

Could someone please advise on this? If you need more detail please comment and I'll provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For those who are also interested in this, I've posted the solution:

The `ngx.header['WWW-Authenticate']` command stops the script and sends a new request. No type of variable, be it in NGINX or Lua, can hold it's value across requests. What you CAN do, is set a cookie that holds that max auth attempts, like this:

```
local auth_tries = ngx.var.cookie_AuthAttempts

if not auth_tries then
  auth_tries = 1
end

if type(auth_tries) == "string" then
  auth_tries = tonumber(auth_tries)
end
```

Then set the counter at the end of the loop, and set the cookie to its value:

```
auth_header = nil
auth_tries = auth_tries + 1

ngx.header['Set-Cookie'] = "AuthAttempts="..auth_tries.."; Path=/; Expires="..ngx.cookie_time(ngx.time() + 3600*24)
```

Then, if the max failed attempts have been reached, clean up, and send the 401 response:

```
ngx.header['Set-Cookie'] = "AuthAttempts=0; Path=/; Expires="..ngx.cookie_time(ngx.time() + 3600*24)

if res ~= nil then
if res.status ~= 200 then
  ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
else
  ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Fail2Ban.
Here is an example how-to:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04

Solution above doesn't protect from DDoS attack.

Comment: Thanks Alex! The above solutions was meant for users using a browser to access the site. In case a valid user puts in the wrong password by mistake. I didn't want to ban them outright from the site. Fail2Ban will be set up separately for DDoS attacks. Quick question though, how do I test F2B without getting MY ip address banned?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/285256/how-to-unban-an-ip-properly-with-fail2ban